# Convert text into PDF

Tags: java, pdf, raw-data

I have a huge string of text that is apparently raw data for a PDF file, and I need to make it back into a PDF.

Currently I'm reading the string into a StringBuffer but if I need to I can change that. From there I have tried just writing it out to a file and changing the extension (I really hoped that worked, but I kinda knew it wouldn't), I've tried taking it to a String then getting a byte[] out of it and writing that to the file or using a DataOutputStream to put the bytes into the file. None of these has seemed to work.

I've also tried using the iText plugin, I tried just writing it to a pdf through that and I also tried reading the text as a pdf and then copying it page by page to a new pdf. Neither of these have returned very good results.

It's Friday afternoon, I'm tapped, any suggestions will be a huge help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well after a lot of research I found out that to preserve the binary data in the string that typically you convert it to Base64 encoding. On a complete guess I decoded the string out of Base64 and dropped the bytes into the pdf file, and lo and behold I had a pdf that could be opened!

Thanks for the answers and I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 4):

The iText approach is the right one. You can do something like this :

```
import java.io.*;

import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

public class TextFileToPDF {

  /*
     ex. java TextFileToPDF  c:\temp\text.txt  c:\temp\text.pdf
  */
  public static void main (String [] args){
    BufferedReader input = null;
    Document output = null;
    System.out.println("Convert text file to pdf");
    System.out.println("input  : " + args[0]);
    System.out.println("output : " + args[1]);
    try {
      // text file to convert to pdf as args[0]
      input = 
        new BufferedReader (new FileReader(args[0]));
      // letter 8.5x11
      //    see com.lowagie.text.PageSize for a complete list of page-size constants.
      output = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 40, 40, 40, 40);
      // pdf file as args[1]
      PdfWriter.getInstance(output, new FileOutputStream (args[1]));

      output.open();
      output.addAuthor("RealHowTo");
      output.addSubject(args[0]);
      output.addTitle(args[0]);

      String line = "";
      while(null != (line = input.readLine())) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(line);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        output.add(p);
      }
      System.out.println("Done.");
      output.close();
      input.close();
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken wouldn't this just print the raw data into a pdf, thus giving me a long jarbled string of text in a pdf?

Comment: No, the "\n" marks a new paragraph and each paragraph will be justified.

Comment: Great solution, just a thing: in case of empty `line`, in the while loop, I've had to valorize it as `line = "\n";` in order to preserve empty lines in the initial txt.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is a binary object. You need to write the bytes directly to a file.

Turning into text will probably break it. Does it start with `%%PDF-` and end with `%%EOF`?

Comment: It does not have those flags, it's just text in between XML tags.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines and last few so we can see?

Comment: Once I decoded out of Base64 those tags there there, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How did you come across this string? If it is a raw ASCII string, you will be missing a large amount of binary data that is embedded within the PDF.

If you have a unicode string, you may be able to write it to a file directly using an OutputStream (not a Writer as you don't actually want to write character data).

Comment: it's in a file that my company get's from another company... that's about all I can say about where it comes from. I tried using a basic DataOutputStream to write the byte[] to a pdf, but I think I'm going to try bypassing the string buffer see if that works.