# TXT to PDF in Java using Native lib

Tags: java, pdf, native

I could not find anywhere an answer to that. Is it possible to create a PDF file from a String or txt file using only native libs in Java? If so, how can one do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert text into PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696463/convert-text-into-pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by *native libs*? Are you referring to JNI?

Comment: why would you not want to use a library for this? You can write the bytes yourself if you like and have lots of time